# How to change default aesthetics in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, default, aesthetics

Let's say that I would prefer `geom_point` to use circles (`pch=1`) instead of solid dots (`pch=16`) by default. You can change the shape of the markers by passing a `shape` argument to `geom_point`, e.g.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(depth, carat, colour=cut)) + geom_point(shape=1)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(depth, carat, colour=cut)) + geom_point(shape=16)
```

but I can't figure out how to change the default behaviour.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Geom (and stat) default can be updated directly:

```
update_geom_defaults("point", list(shape = 1))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

One way to do it (although I don't really like it) is to make your own geom_point function. E.g.

```
geom_point2 <- function(...) geom_point(shape = 1, ...)
```

Then just use as normal:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(depth, carat, colour=cut)) + geom_point2()
```

Or if you want you can override the function `geom_point()`:

```
geom_point <- function(...) {
  ggplot2::geom_point(shape = 1, ...)
}
```

This might be considered bad practice but it works. Then you don't have to change how you plot:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(depth, carat, colour=cut)) + geom_point()
```