# ggplot2: use colour / shape / ... inside and outside of aes() in a flexible plotting function

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

**The goal**

I'd like to have a function that processes some input `X` and produces a `gglot` graph using `geom_point`.

That function should allow to map columns of `X` to various aesthetics inside `aes()` (via arguments `.shapefac`, `.colfac`, etc.), but also allow to set e.g. point colour and shape manually (e.g. `colour = "tomato"`), outside of `aes()`.

**The problem**

If `.shapefac` or `.colfac` arguments are provided, the aesthetics get overridden by the specification of `shape` and `colour`, respectively. This is explained e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511911/difference-between-passing-options-in-aes-and-outside-of-it-in-ggplot2).

**What I've tried**

One workaround would be to remove the `shape` and `colour` arguments, and allow them to be specified using `...` in `geom_point`. This works, but needs some advanced R knowledge for a user of such a function.

**The question**

Does anybody know if there is

- a way to change the default setting for the `shape` and `colour` arguments outside of `aes()` in `geom_point`?
- a way to override the specification of the `shape` and `colour` arguments, if an aesthetic is used?
- another way to reach the goal stated above, without using `...`?

Any hints or explanations are much appreciated!

The following function and plots hopefully illustrate the problem.

**define function**

```r
library(mlbench)
data("Ionosphere")

cplot <- function(X, v = 1:ncol(X), .shapefac = NULL, .colfac = NULL, shape = 21, colour = "black",
                  center = TRUE, scale = FALSE, x = 1, y = 2, plot = TRUE) {
  
  library(ggplot2)
  # some code processing X to Y
  d.pca <- prcomp(X, center = center, scale. = scale)
  Y <- data.frame(X, d.pca$x)
  v <- round(100 * (d.pca$sdev^2 / sum(d.pca$sdev^2)), 2)
  
  # plot PCA
  p <- ggplot(Y, aes_string(x = paste0("PC",x), y = paste0("PC",y))) +
    geom_point(aes_string(shape = .shapefac, colour = .colfac),
               shape = shape, color = colour) +
    labs(x = paste0("PC ", x, " (", v[x], "%)"),
         y = paste0("PC ", x, " (", v[y], "%)")) +
    theme_bw()
  if (plot) print(p)
  invisible(p)
}
```

**setting colour and shape arguments outside aes()**

This works as it should.

```r
cplot(Ionosphere, v = 3:34, colour = "tomato", shape = 4)
```

[image]

**setting shape inside `aes()` when shape outside `aes()` has a default of 21**

The default `shape = 21` outside `aes()` overrides the shape aesthetic.

```r
cplot(Ionosphere, v = 3:34, .shapefac = "Class")
```

[image]

**setting colour inside `aes()` when colour outside `aes()` has a default of "black"**

The default `colour = "black"` outside `aes()` overrides the colour aesthetic.

```r
cplot(Ionosphere, v = 3:34, .colfac = "Class")
```

[image]

**failed trials to set default shape and colour to `NULL`or `NA`**

```r
# results in an empty plot (shape = NA)
cplot(Ionosphere, v = 3:34, .shapefac = "Class", shape = NA)
#> Warning: Removed 351 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

```r
# results in an error
cplot(Ionosphere, v = 3:34, .shapefac = "Class", shape = NULL)
#> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (351): shape
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I saw some ideas for changing the default point shape here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196804/how-to-change-default-aesthetics-in-ggplot

Comment: how should a mapping on `"Class"` work if you remove it from the data? -> `Ionosphere[,-c(1,2,35)]`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, not sure why reprex still worked, probably because X was assigned. I fixed it in the question.

Comment: @aosmith I think this is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result may look like so:

1. If the aesthetics are provided set the color and/or shape params to `NULL`
2. Make use of `modifyList` to construct a list of arguments to be passed to `geom_point` which includes the mapping and the non-NULL parameters. Making use `modifyList` will drop any `NULL`.
3. Make use of `do.call` to call `geom_point` with the list of arguments.

Note: I slightly changed your function to select only numeric columns for the PCA.

```r
library(mlbench)
library(ggplot2)

data(Ionosphere)

cplot <- function(X, .shapefac = NULL, .colfac = NULL, shape = 21, colour = "black",
                  center = TRUE, scale = FALSE, x = 1, y = 2, plot = TRUE) {
  
  col_numeric <- unlist(lapply(X, is.numeric))
  
  # some code processing X to Y
  d.pca <- prcomp(X[, col_numeric], center = center, scale. = scale)
  Y <- data.frame(X, d.pca$x)
  v <- round(100 * (d.pca$sdev^2 / sum(d.pca$sdev^2)), 2)
  
  colour <- if (is.null(.colfac)) colour
  shape <- if (is.null(.shapefac)) shape
  
  mapping <- aes_string(shape = .shapefac, colour = .colfac)
  args <- modifyList(list(mapping = mapping), list(color = colour, shape = shape))
  
  geom <- do.call("geom_point", args)
  
  p <- ggplot(Y, aes_string(x = paste0("PC", x), y = paste0("PC", y))) +
    geom +
    labs(
      x = paste0("PC ", x, " (", v[x], "%)"),
      y = paste0("PC ", x, " (", v[y], "%)")
    ) +
    theme_bw()
  if (plot) print(p)
  invisible(p)
}

cplot(Ionosphere, colour = "tomato", shape = 4)
```

[image]

```r
cplot(Ionosphere, .shapefac = "Class")
```

[image]

```r
cplot(Ionosphere, .colfac = "Class")
```

[image]

```r
cplot(Ionosphere, .colfac = "Class", .shapefac = "Class")
```

[image]

```r
cplot(Ionosphere, .shapefac = "Class", shape = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow @stefan, this is exactly what I was looking for! Interesting use of `if`, and I learnt about `modifyList`. This solution also seems better compared to using `update_geom_defaults`, because it truly overrides any specification of e.g. `shape` if `.shapefac` is given, also for the legend.